# simple calculation in java - let user know they have to use a valid operator

Tags: java, while-loop, calculator

I am writing a basic calculator program in java using JOptionPane. I am very new to this and any help with the problem I am having is really appreciated! I have tried to research this online but I only come across answers where Scanner is imported or the order of user input is different than mine.

My program is suppose to ask users for a number, than has them select the operator to use (+,-,*,/,%) and than asks users for a second number. After all this, the calculation is performed and a result is displayed.

Is it possible to use a while loop (not a do while loop) to check for an invalid operator before the second number is entered? 
I have working code that checks for the invalid operator after the second number is entered but I'd like to find a way to check it beforehand and than re-ask users for an operator until a valid one is entered.

```
    while (!useCalculator) { 
    num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your first number:");
    numOne = Double.parseDouble(num1);

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Thank you! What would you like to do?\nPlease choose from the following options:\n+\n-\n*\n%\n/");

    num2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Thank you!\nPlease enter your second number:");
    numTwo = Double.parseDouble(num2);

    if (input != null && input.equals("+"))
    {add(numOne, numTwo);
    result = add(numOne, numTwo); //I have this as a separate mehtod
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result of " + numOne + " " + input + " " + numTwo + " is: " + result);
    }
    else if (input != null && input.equals("-"))
    {minus(numOne, numTwo);
    result = minus(numOne, numTwo);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result of " + numOne + " " + input + " " + numTwo + " is: " + result);
    }
    else if (input != null && input.equals("*"))
    {  multiply(numOne, numTwo);
   result = multiply(numOne, numTwo);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result of " + numOne + " " + input + " " + numTwo + " is: " + result);
    }
    else if (input != null && input.equals("/"))
    { divide(numOne, numTwo);
   result = divide(numOne, numTwo);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result of " + numOne + " " + input + " " + numTwo + " is: " + result);
    }
    else if (input != null && input.equals("%"))
     { modul(numOne, numTwo);
   result = modul(numOne, numTwo);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result of " + numOne + " " +     input + " " + numTwo + " is: " + result);
    }

    else  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "The operator is invalid. Please select a correct operator.\nPlease choose from the following options:\n+\n-\n*\n%\n/");
```

The thing is, I want to understand and learn how to do this. I have added part of my code for guidance (I can add the whole thing if needed) but what I am really looking for is an explanation on how to accomplish this so I can try it out on my own and work my way through it. I apologize if this is broad, I'd be happy to clear anything up if needed! :)

Thank you all,
T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just insert an inner while at line #6 as follows:

```
while(input==null || !(input.equals("+") ||input.equals("*") || input.equals("/") || input.equals("-"))){
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "The operator has to to be either *,+,/,-")
}
```

Comment: Maybe switch statement would look cleaner.

Comment: This was perfect- thank you @simonarame (and everyone else!). I really appreciate the quick and courteous help- being new to java it is nice to have :)

Answer (score 0):

Lexical analyzers typically handle a full string identifying each lexeme (smallest units, like '+' and variables) in turn, so it may be faster to ask for an expression, e.g., 2*4+5, and identify each part in like fashion as opposed to prompting the user several times, returning an error if they're unsuccessful.